# Using specified db in Django connection

Tags: django, database

I'm using Django to do some db query:

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
        cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

And below is my db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ka_a',
        'USER': 'ka_a',
        'PASSWORD': 'ka_a',
        'HOST': 'xxx',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'STORAGE_ENGINE': 'INNODB',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "set sql_mode='traditional'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4'
        }
    },
    'ka_b': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ka_b',
        'USER': 'ka_b',
        'PASSWORD': 'ka_b',
        'HOST': 'xxxxx',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'STORAGE_ENGINE': 'INNODB',
    },
}

KA_B = 'ka_b'
```

How can I select to `KA_B` in  `connection`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in doc:

If you need to access the DatabaseWrapper object itself, use `connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]` instead.

```
from django.db import connections

connection = connections[settings.KA_B]

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    ...
```